# Grouping data on unique column keys and joining (pivot table) in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe, financial

I am new to pandas and python and am trying to reshape data that was provided in a .csv. The data is structured such that the tickers with respective closes and dates are sequential in the same column.

For example:

```
               TIC     CLOSE
DATE                        
1984-01-03   0223B  25.37500
1984-01-04   0223B  25.75000
1984-01-05   0223B  25.75000
1983-12-30   0485B  21.37500
1984-01-03   0485B  21.37500
1984-01-04   0485B  22.50000
1983-12-30   0491B  17.75000
1984-01-03   0491B  17.50000
1984-01-04   0491B  17.62500
1983-12-30   3614B  74.25000
1984-01-03   3614B  73.25000
1984-01-04   3614B  76.00000
1993-07-01   3615B  47.25000
1993-07-02   3615B  47.25000
1993-07-06   3615B  46.40625
1983-12-30  3ABNKQ   4.75000
1984-01-03  3ABNKQ   5.00000
1984-01-04  3ABNKQ   5.62500
1983-12-30   3ACKH  55.25000
1984-01-03   3ACKH  54.50000
1984-01-04   3ACKH  55.25000
```

I want to reshape the data so that I'll have a pandas dataframe where each column will be a ticker with its respective closes and if there is no data for the date row key it will have NaN ('left' join).

I have tried something like this:

```
sp = pd.read_csv('D:\Stocks.csv')
sp = pd.DataFrame(sp)
sp.columns = ['TIC', 'DATE', 'CLOSE']
sp.index = pd.to_datetime(sp['DATE'])
sp = sp[['TIC', 'CLOSE']]
unique_tickers = sp['TIC'].unique()

s0 = sp[sp['TIC'] == unique_tickers[0]]
s0 = pd.DataFrame(s0['CLOSE'])
s1 = sp[sp['TIC'] == unique_tickers[1]]
s1 = pd.DataFrame(s1['CLOSE'])

s0s1 = pd.concat([s0, s1], axis = 1)
s0s1.columns = unique_tickers[0:2]

for i in range(len(unique_tickers)):
    sx = sp[sp['TIC'] == unique_tickers[i]]
    sx = pd.DataFrame(sx['CLOSE'])
    s0s1 = pd.concat([s0s1, sx], axis = 1)
```

I guess I could hack the above code to get it to work, but I assume there is a much more elegant solution. Any ideas?

Thanks!

I got the solution to the original issues which was (thanks to BrenBarn):

```
sp = sp.reset_index().pivot(index='DATE', columns="TIC", values="CLOSE")
```

But when I ran it on a larger .csv I ran into the following bug,

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

I tried to find a solution by trying to sp.groupby('TIC') then take all unique 'Date' row keys but it can figure out the syntax.. again any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> d.reset_index().pivot(index='DATE', columns="TIC", values="CLOSE")
TIC          0223B   0485B   0491B  3614B     3615B  3ABNKQ  3ACKH
DATE                                                              
1983-12-30     NaN  21.375  17.750  74.25       NaN   4.750  55.25
1984-01-03  25.375  21.375  17.500  73.25       NaN   5.000  54.50
1984-01-04  25.750  22.500  17.625  76.00       NaN   5.625  55.25
1984-01-05  25.750     NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN    NaN
1993-07-01     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  47.25000     NaN    NaN
1993-07-02     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  47.25000     NaN    NaN
1993-07-06     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  46.40625     NaN    NaN
```

I had to use `reset_index` because `pivot` requires a column as index (at least until [this bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3962) is fixed).

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly it.. I thought it had to be pivot, but couldn't get to work..